# Android gradle build fail with BindException when VPN turned on

Tags: android, gradle, nativescript

I have VPN on my computer and when I try to build android, specifically from native script, it will show `java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Cannot bind`.

When I tried `./gradlew.bat --debug`, it seems to be failing while doing something with a VPN network.

I can work around by disabling VPN during build. But is it possible to just make the build process skip the VPN network?

Comment: maybe use --offline flag?

Comment: posted an answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to provide an additional parameter to gradlew, namely `--offline`, in order to execute the selected task without accessing the network.

This works fine if your dependencies have already been cached locally on your machine otherwise Gradle still need to access internet in order to fetch the required libraries (at least the first time).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what happened. I thought it was working yesterday but after carefully checking today, it's not. The issue seems to be with gradle daemon while it's binding it's socket to wild card IP and somehow there's some problem if the VPN is turned on. For now, I'll just temporarily disable vpn while starting up the build.